# integrate iframe offertor wordpress add variable user id with Postback

Tags: wordpress, variables, iframe

good, not yet and tried nothing since I don't know much about programming, only some basic code, integrate this iframe }/10342" frameborder="0" width="500" height="2400"> I have to give you variable user id and Postback leagradesco your prompt help

Comment: Its the first question of you, nice. It's very much easy for the reader who wants to answer to your question if the title and description follows :

1. Appropriate English word with punctuation.
2. Description should start with the problem you are facing. After that go into deeper.

Comment: I have to recreate the consultation or